# Max n for which sum of exponential distribution is bigger then gamma variable

Tags: self-study, gamma-distribution, exponential-distribution

I am currently preparing to the actuarial exam and it is one of the exercises from previous years I encountered and have no idea how to deal with:
Let us assume that $X_1, X_2,  ..., X_n$ are independent, exponentially distributed random variable. $EX_i = \frac{1}{2}$. Note also that $T_0 = 0, T_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ for $i = 1, 2, ...$ . $Y$ is also a random variable with the following probability function: $p(x) = 32 x^2 \exp\{-4x\}$  for $x  \geq 0 $. 
Besides we have also a variable N which is defined as: $ N = max \{ n \geq 0: T_n \leq Y \}$ What is the probability distribution function of the variable $N$?

---

I know the correct answer which is the following: $P(N=n) = \frac{1}{2} (n+1)(n+2)(\frac{8}{27})(\frac{1}{3})^n$ but I have no idea how to derive this solution. I know that Y is gamma distributed but it doesn't help much. I denoted: $X = X_{n+1}, Z = X_1 + \ldots + X_n$ and tried to do something with the following equations $P(X+Z > Y | X < Y)$ but I don't really have any good idea how to deal with it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: For this to be answerable you'd also need to know the dependence structure between $Y$ and the $X_i$, which is not stated.

Answer (score 2):

A few hints.  I have not completed the problem myself yet, but some things seem quite relevant.

1)  A sum of iid exponentially distributed random variables is gamma distributed with integer shape parameter.

2)  $T_n$ is monotone increasing.  Obviously,
$$
Pr(T_n > Y, T_{n-1} < Y) = Pr(T_n > Y) - Pr(T_n > Y, T_{n-1} > Y).
$$
Now since $T_n$ is monotone increasing, that last term equal $Pr(T_{n-1} > Y)$.

3) So from (2) we know all we need to be able to calculate is $Pr(T_n > Y)$.  I don't immediately know of an identities for comparing gamma distribution but you can try just doing the double integral.

Comment: +1 ... if we had $Y$ independent of all the $X_i$ (which is not stated in the Q) actually $P(T_n>Y)$ would be *easy*. In the form of a big hint for the OP -- recognize $Y$ also has the distribution of a sum of $X$'s (possibly times a constant) and consider $P(T_n/Y > 1)$

Comment: Yes, actually Y and Xs are independent - I forgot to write it above. I'll try to work with it and give you update as soon as I work it out. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work. I tried to calculate those double integrals several times but I don't get the right answer. $P(T_{n+1}>Y) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{x} \frac{2^{n+1}}{\Gamma(n+1)}x^n e^{-2x} 32 y^2 e^{-4x} dy dx = 1 - (n+1)(n+2) * \frac{1}{3}^{n+1} \frac{8}{36} - \frac{1}{3}^{n+1} * \frac{4(n+1)}{6} - \frac{1}{3}^{n+1}$ and the same integral for $T_n > Y$ equals $1 - (n+1) * \frac{1}{3}^{n} \frac{8}{36} - \frac{1}{3}^{n} * \frac{4n}{6} - \frac{1}{3}^{n}$. However, I think your idea is great, jlimahaverford but I think sth is still missing.

Comment: Should be $e^{-4y}$ in the integral.

Comment: @jlimahaverford You don't need to do an integration for that My comment reduces it to a simple calculation involving a standard distribution.

Comment: Ok, so since $T_n \sim \Gamma (n, 2)$ and $ Y \sim \Gamma (3, 4)$ we can conclude that $\frac{1}{2}Y \sim \Gamma (3, 2).$ So we can conclude farther that (as you wrote earlier) $\frac{T_n}{Y} > 1$ equals to $ \frac{T_n}{0.5 Y} > 2 $. And now I should somehow transform it into a standard normal distribution? I tried using this property that  while $ A \sim \Gamma(a, theta) B \sim \Gamma(b, theta)$ than  $\frac{A}{A+B} \sim Beta(a, b)$ but again, it doesn't solve it. And I guess that here $T_n \neq Y + X_4 + X_5 + \ldots$ because they're independant.

Comment: It's not clear why you would try to make it normal. You coulf try make it beta but if that's what I was after I wouldn't have suggested dividing by Y, but instead adding $T_n$ to both sides before dividing by $T_n+Y$.  What do you know about Gamma(something, 2) distributions?

Comment: Aaaa... Ok, now I get it, that's brilliant! I'm almost there. So $\frac{T_n}{0.5 Y}$ can be transformed to F_Snedecor distribution because both $T_n$ and $Y$ can be transformed to chi square. Ok, so I now I'm back to the point where I have to calculate $P(T_{n+1}>Y) - P(T_n > Y)$ and I have something like this: $F_{(2n+2, 6)}(\frac{6}{n+1}) - F_{(2n, 6)}(\frac{6}{n})$.